# ASP.NET Website CI using Azure Dev Ops Pipeline

Tags: asp.net, build, azure-devops, vs-web-site-project

I've a legacy project, which is a ASP.net Website project(not having .csproj file). It holding .aspx files and packages.config for nuget and other dependencies. Now I want to deploy it to Azure app service by automation with CI/CD in Azure Dev Ops pipeline.
I can't find anything which is suitable for all tasks I need for CI.
Here I don't have .csproj, so I build it using packages.config

Task I tried

1. Update .sln to .config, because I have more than one website in single solution.
   [image]
2. Update Nuget Restore task with install, it doesn't work with restore
   [image]
3. And while queue, this pipeline got failed on Build task
   [image]
4. Error it thrown
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops) task cannot build `packages.config` file, this task uses MSBuild to build. In `Solution` argument, only `.sln` file or `.*proj` file can be specified.

> **Solution**: Required) If you want to build a single solution, click the
> ... button and select the solution.
>
> If you want to build multiple solutions, specify search criteria. You
> can use a single-folder wildcard (`*`) and recursive wildcards (`**`).
> For example, `**.sln` searches for all .sln files in all
> subdirectories.
>
> You can also build MSBuild project (.*proj) files. If you are building
> a customized MSBuild project file, we recommend you use the MSBuild
> task instead of the Visual Studio Build task.
>
> Default value: ***.sln